# How to sum __m256 horizontally?

Tags: sse, vectorization, intrinsics, avx

I would like to horizontally sum the components of a `__m256` vector using AVX instructions.
In SSE I could use

```
_mm_hadd_ps(xmm,xmm);
_mm_hadd_ps(xmm,xmm);
```

to get the result at the first component of the vector, but this does not scale with the 256 bit version of the function (`_mm256_hadd_ps`).

What is the best way to compute the horizontal sum of a `__m256` vector?

Comment: use sse to compute horizontal sum of the lower part; shuffle YMM high / low parts, use sse again and sum up the two scalars. or wait for avx2.

Comment: Is this inside a loop or is it just a one-off operation ?

Comment: It's inside an outer loop where there is another inner loop.

Comment: See also [this 128b SSE answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35270026/224132) for more optimal (lower latency, fewer uops) alternatives to `haddps` after you've done the `vextractf128` / `addps` step.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This version should be optimal for both Intel Sandy/Ivy Bridge and AMD Bulldozer, and later CPUs.

```
// x = ( x7, x6, x5, x4, x3, x2, x1, x0 )
float sum8(__m256 x) {
    // hiQuad = ( x7, x6, x5, x4 )
    const __m128 hiQuad = _mm256_extractf128_ps(x, 1);
    // loQuad = ( x3, x2, x1, x0 )
    const __m128 loQuad = _mm256_castps256_ps128(x);
    // sumQuad = ( x3 + x7, x2 + x6, x1 + x5, x0 + x4 )
    const __m128 sumQuad = _mm_add_ps(loQuad, hiQuad);
    // loDual = ( -, -, x1 + x5, x0 + x4 )
    const __m128 loDual = sumQuad;
    // hiDual = ( -, -, x3 + x7, x2 + x6 )
    const __m128 hiDual = _mm_movehl_ps(sumQuad, sumQuad);
    // sumDual = ( -, -, x1 + x3 + x5 + x7, x0 + x2 + x4 + x6 )
    const __m128 sumDual = _mm_add_ps(loDual, hiDual);
    // lo = ( -, -, -, x0 + x2 + x4 + x6 )
    const __m128 lo = sumDual;
    // hi = ( -, -, -, x1 + x3 + x5 + x7 )
    const __m128 hi = _mm_shuffle_ps(sumDual, sumDual, 0x1);
    // sum = ( -, -, -, x0 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 )
    const __m128 sum = _mm_add_ss(lo, hi);
    return _mm_cvtss_f32(sum);
}
```

`haddps` is not efficient on any CPU; the best you can do is one shuffle (to extract the high half) and one add, repeat until one element left.  Narrowing to 128-bit as the first step benefits AMD before Zen2, and is not a bad thing anywhere.

See [Fastest way to do horizontal SSE vector sum on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-sse-vector-sum-on-x86) for more details about efficiency.

Comment: There are some weird corner cases (when performance is decode-bound) where using `haddps` instead would confer a benefit, but generally this is very reasonable.

Comment: On Bulldozer haddps is microcoded. Moreover, it will generate 3 macrooperations, while the code above uses only 2 for partial reduction.

Comment: which is why I said "weird corner cases" (they are very rare, and truly weird).

Comment: Doesn't the use of SSE instructions (like _mm_movehl_ps) with 256bit AVX instructions incur a state change penalty?

Comment: SSE instructions do cause state change penalty, but if you compile for AVX instruction sets, `_mm_movehl_ps` and the likes would generate AVX forms of the instructions (`VMOVHLPS` in this particular case).

Answer (score 7):

This can be done with the following code:

```
ymm2 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(ymm , ymm , 1);
ymm = _mm256_add_ps(ymm, ymm2);
ymm = _mm256_hadd_ps(ymm, ymm);
ymm = _mm256_hadd_ps(ymm, ymm);
```

but there might be a better solution.

Comment: I noticed that the permute + add can also come *after* the two hadds.