# Store the sum of a __m256 vector without the AVX-to-SSE transition penalty?

Tags: simd, avx

Does the following code incur the AVX-to-SSE transition penalty?  If so, how can I store the sum of a __m256 vector without incurring this penalty?

```
__mm256 x_swap = _mm_permute2f128_ps(x,x,1)
x = _mm256_add_ps(x, x_swap);
x = _mm256_hadd_ps(x,x);
x = _mm256_hadd_ps(x,x);  // now all fields of x contain the sum

float sum;
_mm_store_ss(&sum, _mm256_castps256_ps128(x));
```

Thank you.

Comment: That's not an efficient way to hsum a vector; `vhaddps` is slow (at least 2 shuffle uops plus a vertical add, and slower on some CPUs especially the 256-bit version).  [How to sum \_\_m256 horizontally?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13219146) and in general [Fastest way to do horizontal SSE vector sum (or other reduction)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6996764)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So long as you compile your code with `-mavx` then you shouldn't see any AVX-SSE transition penalties. When compiling with `-mavx` you automatically use the newer non-destructive SSE opcodes and there are no penalties when mixing these with AVX instructions. The penalties are only incurred when you mix legacy SSE instructions with AVX, and typically this only happens with assembly code or when mixing modules which have been compiled with different flags.