# Why both? vperm2f128 (avx) vs vperm2i128 (avx2)

Tags: intel, simd, avx, avx2

avx introduced the instruction `vperm2f128` (exposed via `_mm256_permute2f128_si256`), while avx2 introduced `vperm2i128` (exposed via `_mm256_permute2x128_si256`).

They both seem to be doing exactly the same, and their respective latencies and throughputs also seem to be identical.

So why do both instructions exist? There has to be some reasoning behind that? Is there maybe something I have overlooked? Given that avx2 operates on data structures introduced with avx, I cannot imagine that a processor will ever exist that supports avx2 but not avx.

Comment: Same reason as why there are load/store and logical instructions for both integers and floating-point in SSE/AVX: some microarchitectures partition the vector-units between floating-point FPU and integer ALU (probably to improve locality on the chip, keeping wires short), so that moving data between floating-point and integer is slow.

Comment: I don't completely follow your reasoning. The signature for the `f` version is `__m256i _mm256_permute2f128_si256 (__m256i a, __m256i b, int imm8)`, and Intel's description reads _Shuffle 128-bits (composed of integer data)_ (it's exactly the same as for `permute2x128`). Given that it takes `__m256i` as arguments, shouldn't they be in the integer ALU? Or are you saying a `__m256i` can be loaded in the FPU?

Answer (score 9):

There's a bit of a disconnect between the intrinsics and the actual instructions that are underneath.

**AVX:**

All 3 of these generate exactly the same instruction, `vperm2f128`:

- `_mm256_permute2f128_pd()`
- `_mm256_permute2f128_ps()`
- `_mm256_permute2f128_si256()`

The only difference are the types - which don't exist at the instruction level.

`vperm2f128` is a 256-bit floating-point instruction. In AVX, there are no "real" 256-bit integer SIMD instructions. So even though `_mm256_permute2f128_si256()` is an "integer" intrinsic, it's really just syntax sugar for this:

```
_mm256_castpd_si256(
    _mm256_permute2f128_pd(
        _mm256_castsi256_pd(x),
        _mm256_castsi256_pd(y),
        imm
    )
);
```

Which does a round trip from the integer domain to the FP domain - thus incurring bypass delays. As ugly as this looks, it is only way to do it in AVX-only land.

`vperm2f128` isn't the only instruction to get this treatment, I find at least 3 of them:

- `vperm2f128` / `_mm256_permute2f128_si256()`
- `vextractf128` / `_mm256_extractf128_si256()`
- `vinsertf128` / `_mm256_insertf128_si256()`

Together, it seems that the usecase of these intrinsics is to load data as 256-bit integer vectors, and shuffle them into multiple 128-bit integer vectors for integer computation. Likewise the reverse where you store as 256-bit vectors.

Without these "hack" intrinsics, you would need to use a lot of cast intrinsics.

Either way, a competent compiler will try to optimize the types as well. Thus it will generate floating-point load/stores and shuffles even if you are using 256-bit integer loads. This reduces the number of bypass delays to only one layer. (when you go from FP-shuffle to 128-bit integer computation)

---

**AVX2:**

AVX2 cleans up this madness by adding proper 256-bit integer SIMD support for everything - including the shuffles.

The `vperm2i128` instruction is new along with a new intrinsic for it, `_mm256_permute2x128_si256()`.

This, along with `_mm256_extracti128_si256()` and `_mm256_inserti128_si256()` lets you do 256-bit integer SIMD and actually stay completely in the integer domain.

---

The distinction between integer FP versions of the same instructions has to do with bypass delays. In older processors, there were delays to move data from int <-> FP domains. While the SIMD registers themselves are type-agnostic, the hardware implementation isn't. And there is extra latency to get data output by an FP instruction to an input to an integer instruction. (and vice versa)

Thus it was important (from a performance standpoint) to use the correct instruction type to match the actual datatype that was being operated on.

On the newest processors (Skylake and later?), there doesn't seem to be anymore int/FP bypass delays with regards to the shuffle instructions. While the instruction set still has this distinction, shuffle instructions that do the same thing with different "types" probably map to the same uop now.

Comment: Intel since SnB hasn't had vec-int/fp bypass delays for the shuffle ALU, I think.  BTW, the question wasn't asking about intrinsics, just about why AVX2 introduced a new mnemonic (with a different opcode) for an integer version of the same shuffle.  But yes, vec-int / FP domain is clearly the reason, future-proofing machine code for CPUs which do have a bypass delay for `vperm2f/i128` between chains of `vpaddb` or `vmulps` instructions.  Same reason that `vpermps` and `vpermd` both exist, and various other pairs.

Comment: Blends *do* have domain-crossing latency on recent Intel.  (Like `vpblendd` vs. `vblendps`).  Blends take many fewer transistors than shuffles, and may be replicated in each domain instead of having a shared ALU with muxing to/from both domains on the inputs/outputs.